# php strpos not finding results in output from database

Tags: php, laravel-5

in my laravel5 controller I take some rows from DB:

```
$order = Order::select('ordered_by')->where('column1','=','1')->get();
```

then in my view, where I render a table,

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     @if(strpos($order, $user->id) == true) match! @endif
@endforeach
```

I get result

```
[{"ordered_by":"309"},{"ordered_by":"524"},{"ordered_by":"541"},{"ordered_by":"545"}]
```

Why strpos not working? (Actually it gives me "match!" in table only for user #546)
Tried this:

```
@if (in_array($user->id,$order) ==true ) ok @endif
```

but it shows me error `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

How can I check if `$user->id` exists in `$order` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$order  = Order::where('column1','=','1')->get();
$orders = array_pluck(collect($order)->toArray(), 'ordered_by');

@foreach($users as $user)
    @if(in_array($user->id, $orders))
        ok
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Now I know about helper functoins! Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**strpos** — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring **in a string**

You can got it using **in_array**

**Try given script**

```
$order = Order::select('ordered_by')->where('column1','=','1')->get()->toArray();

@foreach($users as $user)
     @if (in_array($user->id,$order)) ok @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Now I get array with 4 arrays in it. Then I used print_r but stristr again works wrongly.. It "says" OK only to user #546..
dd shows that: array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "ordered_by" => "309"
  ]
  1 => arr...